# Why is the partner_id field filled in in one tab, but not in the other, even though the module and view are the same?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have landed costs in odoo, and there are two documents there: Journal Entry and Vendor Bill. If I go to the Vendor Bill, then in the partner_id tab I have all the fields filled in, but if I go to the Journal Entry in the same tab, the partner_id field is empty. Despite the fact that this is the same module and the same view.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to override the _create_account_move_line function, which will fill in the debit and credit fields, but it didn't help me.